# Laravel, how to use react-laravel package?

Tags: package, reactjs, laravel-5

I just found this [package](https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel) on github but I do not really understand how get a component rendered.

installed over composer

added the required files to my view

```
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/react-laravel/react.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('js/components.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ asset('vendor/react-laravel/react_ujs.js') }}"></script>
```

controller which calls the view

```
public function index()
{
    $networks = NetworkModel::get();
    return view('backend/pages/networks')->with('networks',$networks);
}
```

the components.js

```
  var Networks = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      return (
        <div className="Networks">
         <ul>
         <li>Test</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      );
    }
  });
```

added to my blade template

```
@react_component('Networks', [ 'title' => 'Networks' ], [ 'prerender' => true ])
```

JS files are loaded properly no error on console
but at the end I have the raw output

```
@react_component('Networks', [ 'title' => 'Networks' ], [ 'prerender' => true ])
```

what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Any luck? I'm looking at this too

Comment: Maybe this helps https://github.com/talyssonoc/react-laravel/issues/28#issuecomment-114667043